# Convert single-precision, floating-point value to Int 16 using Accelerate framework

Tags: ios, swift, accelerate-framework, vdsp

How to convert single precision floating-point to int 16 with help of Accelerate framework.

Int16 to float:

```
import Accelerate

let rr: [Int16] = [ 18, 21, 41, 42, 48, 50, 55, 90]

var float = [Float](repeating: 0, count: rr.count)

vDSP_vflt16(rr, 1, &float, 1, vDSP_Length(rr.count))
```

now i'm try to revert it Float to Int16 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [vDSP_vfix16](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1449992-vdsp_vfix16) :

```
var ints = [Int16](repeating: 0, count: rr.count)

vDSP_vfix16(float, 1, &ints, 1, vDSP_Length(float.count))

print(ints)

// [18, 21, 41, 42, 48, 50, 55, 90]
```

`vDSP_vfix16` rounds towards 0. You can find other functions that use other rounding rules in the **"Single-Vector Floating Point to 16-Bit Integer Conversion"** section [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vdsp/type_conversion#3089570).

Answer (score 2):

There's also [`floatingPointToInteger`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vdsp/3240963-floatingpointtointeger) in the vDSP Swift Overlay:

```
let floats: [Float] = [ 18, 21, 41, 42, 48, 50, 55, 90]

let ints = vDSP.floatingPointToInteger(floats,
                                       integerType: Int16.self,
                                       rounding: .towardNearestInteger)

print(ints) // Prints "[18, 21, 41, 42, 48, 50, 55, 90]"
```

Comment: Note that this requires macOS 10.15/iOS 13, or later.