# Convert array of Int8 to array of Float and reverse it

Tags: swift

How to convert array of `Int8` to array of `Float` again revert it.

I have function to filter float data, so i need to first convert it to `[Float]` and process it and again convert it to `[Int8]` and feed it

Comment: Apparently you know how to do with with Int16: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60462837/1187415 . Have you tried to modify that solution for Int8 ?

Comment: Actually i'm trying to equalize audio which hase PCM in Int8 https://github.com/muhku/FreeStreamer/blob/master/FreeStreamer/FreeStreamer/audio_stream.cpp#L1659

Comment: @MartinR can you help me for -> https://github.com/bartolsthoorn/NVDSP/issues/41

Answer (score 1):

`map` is your friend. You have 2 approaches using this function:

1.

```swift
    let myArray: [UInt8] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    let processedArray = myArray.map { element in
        let floatElement = Float(element)
        // process float
        return Int8(floatElement)
    }
```

2.

```swift
    let myArray: [UInt8] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    let processedArray = myArray
        .map { Float($0) } // convert to Float
        .map { operation($0) } // process the float & return a float
        .map { UInt8($0) } // reconvert to UInt8
```

Both are equivalent, but I think the second option is more readable and allows for a bit more flexibility. It's a matter of preference.

Answer (score 1):

```
extension Array where Iterator.Element == Int8 {
    var toFloatArray: [Float] {
        return self.map({Float($0)})
    }
}

extension Array where Iterator.Element == Float {
    var toIntArray: [Int8] {
        return self.map({Int8($0)})
    }
}

let myIntArr: [Int8] = [1,2,4]
let myFloatArr: [Float] = myIntArr.toFloatArray
print(myFloatArr)
let newIntArr = myFloatArr.toIntArray
print(newIntArr)
```

Use extensions for clean reusable code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I Got it thanks @ Martin R

```
let rr: [Int8] = [ 18, 21, 41, 42, 48, 50, 55, 90]

var float = [Float](repeating: 0, count: rr.count)

vDSP_vflt8(rr, 1, &float, 1, vDSP_Length(rr.count))



var ints = [Int8](repeating: 0, count: rr.count)

vDSP_vfix8(float, 1, &ints, 1, vDSP_Length(float.count))

print(ints)
```

Comment: You can use [`Array.init(unsafeUninitializedCapacity:initializingWith:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3200717-init) to prevent the need of writing all those 0s over the destination arrays.